# How are value- and reference types handled when passed as a method argument?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, reference

I created a simple console application to demonstrate my problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = 2;
        var str = "John";
        var dt = GetDataTable();

        ChangeValue(a, str, dt);

        var b = a; // **still 2**
        var str2 = str; // **still John**
        var dt2 = dt; // **changed and consists of 2 rows, why??????????????**
    }

    private static void ChangeValue(int a, string str, DataTable dt)
    {
        a += 1;

        str = "Hello " + str;

        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Smith", "London");
    }

    private static DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        var dt =  new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("City");

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John", "London");

        return dt;
    }
}
```

After changing the values of all three variables and re-assigning them, the values of `b` and `str2` are still the same as `a` and `str` but `dt2` consists of two rows which I didn't expect. I thought the value of `dt2` will just consist of 1 row as I don't return anything from my `ChangeValue` method.

Can someone enlighten me a bit?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx + http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx + 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: not an exact duplicate, Jeroen, as this question actually provides working code examples that cover more than just the concept of passing objects by reference; it also covers string immmutability. Also the other question specifically asked about how pass by reference/pass by value works, and this one askes how voids work (more functions in general). Thus, for newer programmers in particular, I think this is a different question, with a different answer.

Comment: @BrianDeragon: fair enough, I edited the post so it does not place the focus on the return type (which is irrelevant here).

Comment: -1 really? Unbelievable SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few concepts going on here:

1. Value types passed into a function will not change, which is why the value of `a` never changed, you're only passing the value of `a` and not actually a reference to the memory location in which `a` resides.
2. `str` and `dt` are reference types and under normal circumstances would have their values changed, because you're passing the memory location and actual object itself to be changed, not just a copy of the value, you can see the links in your comments for more information on that.
3. But, `str` did not change even though it's a reference type, and that's because you bumped into yet another .NET rule, strings are immutable and cannot change. When I say strings are immutable in .NET, that means you cannot change them, see here for more info: [MSDN - string (C# reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).
4. As [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497356/andrew-whitaker) pointed out as well, only changes to the properties or fields of the reference object are passed back. Reassignment, is not; for instance, if you had changed the assignment of `dt` in your `ChangeValue` method to a `new DataTable()` your code would still show the original datatable.

   ```
   private static void ChangeValue(ref int a, string str, DataTable dt)
   {
       a += 1;   
       str = "Hello " + str;    
       dt.Rows.Add(2, "Smith", "London");
       dt = new DataTable();
   }
   ```

**Edited:** On another note, while not part of the concepts you demonstrated in your code sample, as Jeroen pointed out, there is a keyword `ref` that can change how a value type is passed to the function.

For instance, if you changed:

```
private static void ChangeValue(int a, string str, DataTable dt)
{
    a += 1;
    str = "Hello " + str;
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Smith", "London");
}
```

to

```
private static void ChangeValue(ref int a, string str, DataTable dt)
{
    a += 1;
    str = "Hello " + str;
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Smith", "London");
}
```

And then changed

```
ChangeValue(a, str, dt);
```

to

```
ChangeValue(ref a, str, dt);
```

The value of `a` would now change. By including the ref keyword in both the function declaration and when you call it, you're no longer just passing the value, but the actual reference to the object/memory location storing that value. Thus when its changed in your function, a's new value should be 3.

There is also the `out` keyword, which can be used in the same manner, and technically does the same thing. The only difference I am aware of, is variables passed using the `out` keyword do not have to be initialized first, whereas variables passed using the `ref` keyword do. There's also a semantic difference (difference in meaning), as in `out` variables should be variables the function is controlling, that are being passed out from it; while `ref` variables are in the user/programmers control, that the function just happens to need a reference to, and may change the state of.

Also, I added a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uboHXs#) to show the example in more details for you.

Comment: I'm not sure about #3. If `string`s *were* mutable in C# `str` would not change after the method ran. That is, if the OP used a reference type other than `string` the behavior would have been the same. The reason the reassignment doesn't work is because a *copy* of the reference is passed to the method, not because of string immutability.

Comment: technically true as well

Answer (score 2):

This really doesn't have anything to do with the return type of `ChangeValue`, it has to do with how parameters are passed in C#.

By default, parameters are passed *by value*.

- For value types, this means that a copy of the variable you're passing is passed to the method.
- For reference types, this means a copy of the *reference* is passed to the method.

It seems like from your question you understand the first point.

In the case of modifying the `DataTable` parameter, you're not actually reassigning the parameter to a new value (like you are with the `int` and `string` values), you're just modifying a class member.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx):

> When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by the reference, such as the value of a class member.

This change is seen outside the method because both variables (inside `ChangeValue` and `Main`) refer to the same reference.

I'd recommend reading Jon Skeet's article on [*Parameter passing in C#*](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) to get   full understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the Jon Skeet link.